# Using melt function for google sheet data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, pandas-melt

I want to convert columns data to rows in my goggle sheets. Please help me to do this using melt function using jupyter notebook. Also I want updated sheet to be inserted in the same google sheets link but as a new tab. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: How do you imagine an answer to the question? Please add the data and your expected outcome.

Comment: It's likely easier to use [pivot tables](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) within google sheets. The Google Sheets API is very annoying to use.